# ArrayList and GUI problems

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to add an update button to my JTable to update a row of data in the GUI and I keep running into the error:

"The Method getVariable() is undefined for the type ArrayList"

```
JButton updateButton = new JButton("Update");
updateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        int i = jTable_Users.getSelectedRow();                
        if(i >= 0) 
           {
               model.setValueAt(usersData.user_id(), i, 0);
               model.setValueAt(usersData.genre_id(), i, 1);                   
               model.setValueAt(usersData.hair_length(), i, 2);
               model.setValueAt(usersData.user_age(), i, 3);
               model.setValueAt(usersData.getUser_gender(), i, 4);
           }
       else
           {
               System.out.println("Update Error");
           }
}});
```

previous errors were corrected by defining 'model' for example at the start of the class but this has been bugging me for a while now.

The ArrayList is defined at the beginning of the class via:

```
ArrayList<User> usersData = new ArrayList<User>();
Object[] columns =
{"id","genre_id","hair_length","user_fname","user_lname","user_age", 
"user_gender"};
```

I have had trouble with action listeners in the past due to poor teaching and they still confuse me to this day.

Comment: The error message comes with a file and line number. **That** is the relevant code.

Comment: You're calling methods on the ArrayList as if it is a User variable, and it isn't -- it's an ArrayList and you can only call ArrayList methods on it. The ArrayList *contains* User items within it, so you can call `get(int index)` on your ArrayList using the appropriate index, and then call User methods on the object returned.

Comment: e.g., `model.setValueAt(usersData.get(i).user_id(), i, 0);`

Comment: Some similar questions can be found [here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+method+undefined+for+arraylist)

Comment: Ok great thanks! the snip of code above resulted in the syntax errors correcting but now i have a number of compilation errors.

Comment: Then you will need to fix those. I also suggest that you find a tutorial or two on how to use ArrayLists since you've got basic incorrect assumptions on their use. It won't be wasted time.